# How to make on toggle different animation to an item

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate, toggle

I want to make left bar when you click on it animate to CSS `left` 10 and when I click on it again go back to the default CSS.

I tried this code:

```
$('.left-bar').click(function() {
    $('.left-bar').toggle(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            // style change
            left: "-116x"
        }, 500);
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            // style change back
            left: "-185px"
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

Comment: On Stackoverflow you should not use text speak. Write complete english sentences using full words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.toggle` you can do something like below. The example is based from [`.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

In the example I use `.data` to store the state of the element, `isToggled`. An based on this data I can figure out if I can *go in a state* and *come back to previous one*.

```js
var $leftBar = $('.left-bar');
$leftBar.click(function() {
  var isToggled = $leftBar.data('toggled'); // get data
   
  var action = isToggled ? "+=100px" : "-=100px"; 
  $leftBar.animate({ "left": action }, 500);
  
  $leftBar.data('toggled', !isToggled); // set the opposite state of current one
});
```

```css
.left-bar {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-bar"></div>
```

**Notes:**

1. This `"left":"+=100px"` is adding 100px to the existing left variable (eg. if `left = 100` then the result will be `left += 100px = 200px`). `-=100px` means that is substracting 100px (eg. if `left = 100` then the result will be `left -= 100px = 0px`).
2. I didn't use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) because it does what the documentation say:

> Display or hide the matched elements

And you want to **change css** of an element **not to hide and display**.

Comment: no brother i wanna toggle a click thats it :)

no need for all of this JS

Comment: i cant understand this part 
var action = isToggled ? "+=100px" : "-=100px";

Comment: all i wanna know is " ? " this syntax :)

Comment: it's called ternary operator, [see this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#JavaScript)